# Is Threshold an early Earth pyramid?

Tags: novel, sara-douglass, threshold

The final paragraph in *Threshold* is:

> "No.  It has taken eight generations to build, and would take two or three to pull down.  More would die in the process, and I do not think I could stand that.  No.  Fill the shafts and corridors with stone and block up all the entrances.  Then leave the sand to drift over the stone and the memories.  Leave Threshold for future millennia to puzzle over - but leave them no trace of its secret."

Threshold is a very large pyramidal building with a capstone and various internal corridors and chambers.  There is only one.

Is this meant to hint that this was the first Earth (Egypt/Mesoamerican) pyramid, found thousands of years later (and copied by the builders of the rest)?

This is the impression I get from the final sentence, along with "how the pyramids were really built" being a moderately common element of stories, but I don't know enough about them to know whether Threshold matches any close enough or whether this is unrelated (with the story set on a totally different world).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what her original intentions were when this book was written, but then it was a standalone novel and that could have been a possibility.

However, Douglass really liked this story, and she folded it into her Tencendor universe (The Wayfarer's Redemption) and used it as backstory, along with The Hanging Wall (a stand alone set in the Tencendor universe) for a final trilogy, Darkglass Mountain.

She died of cancer a few months after the final book, The Infinity Gate, was released.

Answer (score 0):

Threshold, which is later named Darkglass Mountain, is set in the Tencendor universe, and is located near Aqhat, a major city in the Tyranny of Isembaard.  At the end of The Wayfarer Redemption Trilogy (the second trilogy set in the universe), we learn that

> Tencendor is not on Earth, although the StarGate was created by a crash landing of a vessel from Earth that contained the pieces of Qeteb.  The end of the trilogy shows that DragonStar and Faraday are the origin of Angels (and perhaps Adam and Eve), as they return to Earth to guide the humans.

Because we know definitively that the planet in the Tencendor universe is not Earth, we know that Threshold is not an early Earth pyramid.

Comment: Actually, at the time of The Wayfarer Redemption, Threshold was not a part of the Tencendor universe, it was a stand alone novel that Sara Douglass wrote.  It wasn't until the Darkglass Mountain trilogy that he folded it into the universe, so you wouldn't see any references to it until then.

Comment: Perhaps, but the fact that it ended up as part of the Tencendor universe means it could not have been an Earth pyramid, even if that were initially the intention.

Comment: Right, I just mean that there are no references in the universe to Threshhold until Darkglass Mountain.  So unless you've read those books, you wouldn't know.